# A word that refers to a previously mentioned action

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, word-usage

I am trying to refer back to the action "act swiftly" mentioned previously, but I am not sure if I am in the right direction. I thought of a few possible solutions as follows.

An entire rephrasing of the sentence is welcome.

Any guidance is appreciated.

1.

> What we have learnt from past outbreaks is that one of the crucial
>   factors in controlling the spread of the outbreak is to act swiftly,
>   and it is with **this swiftness that guides our efforts** in combating
>   the latest outbreak.

2.

> What we have learnt from past outbreaks is that one of the crucial
>   factors in controlling the spread of the outbreak is to act swiftly,
>   and it is with this **mantra that we adhere to** to combat the latest
>   outbreak.

3.

> What we have learnt from past outbreaks is that one of the crucial
>   factors in controlling the spread of the outbreak is to act swiftly,
>   and it is with this **regard that we are adhering to** to combat latest
>   outbreak.

Comment: I think this is Off Topic proofreading. fwiw, I'd go for *...and it is [the primacy of] **this need for swift action** that guides our efforts...*

Comment: Oops my bad. Thanks for the tip. Sorry that I couldn't upvote as of yet.

Comment: Proofreading questions are considered off-topic "unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified." The questioner has identified the source of concern and asked which of three choices would best resolve it, or--alternately--whether a different wording would be better. This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the structure of the second phrase somewhat long-winded and ungainly; I think you can tighten it up:

> What we have learned from past outbreaks is that one of the crucial factors in controlling their spread is to act swiftly; this knowledge guides our efforts in combating the latest outbreak.

*Knowledge* refers back to the lesson of "what we have learned"; if you want to refer specifically to "act swiftly", you could replace *knowledge* with *urgency*.